# If I use a separate thread for logging, will it perform better?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

If I implement a log class or library in a way that the methods (info, warn, debug ...), when called where executed in a separate thread, would my code run faster?

If yes, does slf4j, log4j or any other popular libraries do this?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know :S

Comment: Clearly, the only possible answer is "it depends". Also, with any form of asynchronous logging, it is worth pondering the question of what happens to the not-yet-written messages in the event of your application crashing (and whether the messages leading up to the crash would be useful in figuring out what went wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Log4j uses separate thread depending on Appender type. In most cases FileAppender is used, and it does not involve additional threads.

And I don't recommend you to use logging in separate thread unless you're really experienced in threading issues.